# SQL Server Locking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that connects with a SQL Server database and cycles through batches of records to perform various tasks and then updates the database accordingly (i.e. "success", "error", etc...).

The potential problem I'm running into is that since it takes roughly a minute or so to get through each record (long story), if I have more than one user running the application there's a high chance of "data collisions" or users trying to process the same records at the same time. Which cannot happen if it is to execute properly.

Initially, I thought about adding a `LOCKED` column to help the application determine if the record was already opened by another user, however if the app were to crash or to be exited without completing the record it was currently on, then it would show that record as opened by another user indefinitely... right? Or am I missing an easy solution here?

Anyway, what would be ideal is if it were possible to have the application `SELECT` 100 records at a time, and "lock them out" on the database while the application processes them AND so that other users can run the application and `SELECT` a different set of 100 so as not to overlap. Is that possible? I've tried to do some research on the matter, but to be honest my experience in SQL Server is very limited. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: If the LOCKED column is enough of a solution and the only problem is potential crashes just add a master unlock scheduled task to run in the middle of the night.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/15/sql-server-concurrency-basics-guest-post-by-vinod-kumar/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138026/sql-server-performance-with-many-concurrent-long-running-queries